# Decode RCMM protocol

Tags: microcontroller, ir-receiver

I am trying to decode [RCMM](http://www.sbprojects.com/knowledge/ir/rcmm.php)(philips protocol) using [VISHAY TSOP31536 IR Receiver](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QFjAA&url=http://www.vishay.com/docs/82493/tsop311.pdf&ei=0_GvUrLmDc_NrQe0-oGoCw&usg=AFQjCNHpV5gshSkYvRlV-oBlbnjCNb_0Vw&bvm=bv.57967247,d.bmk) with STM32F207 microcontroller kit. There is sufficient data for RC5 protocol but not even a single site is explaining about RCMM. Even the details of RCMM specified(frame/message details) in documents is **quite different** from what I extracted from the CRO in lab. Where can I find reliable RCMM documentation?

Comment: RCMM (as well as RC6) documentation is only available from Philips RCS (Remote Control Systems) under NDA, so I'm not sure you'll get a complete answer here.

Comment: hey Johan, thnx for your responce. I'll really appreciate if you could provide me some more info regarding this e.g. some more useful Links or Docs if you have.

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't know/have anything about it. (Even RC5, which isn't under NDA, doesn't seem to have a public specification.)

Comment: okk, but anyways thnx for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

> **details of RCMM specified(frame/message details)**

There is some basic information at [this website](http://www.sbprojects.com/knowledge/ir/rcmm.php). That website has a copyright notice and I don't believe including here a precis of the information would be useful.

> **Where can I find reliable RCMM documentation?**

A Philips application note [Implementing a USB-to-Infrared
(Philips RCMM) Dongle](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Datasheets-UEA1/DSAFRAZ0016368.pdf) says

> The RCMM protocol is proprietary; an NDA would be required to obtain the protocol description.

Comment: It's Philips, with one "l". Phillips is the screw type.